# Jquery all selector - fire only one time on clicked div

Tags: jquery, click

i use the the jquery all selector to get an id from a div (from random websites).
The problem is that the click fires multiple times.
How ca i get the id only from the click div?

```
$("*").click(function()
{
    console.log('fire -> '+this.id+' ');
});
```

Comment: Be aware, never use as selector `*` especially to bind event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why event firing multiple times is the click event is getting bubbled up to the Document. Try to use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent event bubbling,

```
$("*").click(function(e)
{
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log('fire -> ' + this.id );
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/1789/)**

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Perfect demonstration.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [StopPropogation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop the propogation of event:

```
$("*").click(function(event)
{
    event.stopPropogation();
    console.log('fire -> '+this.id+' ');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAeY7/)

Answer (score 0):

This is indicating the whole html element. so it is taking only html.

You need to specify the tag. As you are wanting the id of all div. so you need to right like this

```
$('div').click(function(){
    //enter code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was about event bubbling through the DOM. That's said, your selector is the worst you can get, binding an event to absolutely all elements in the DOM. Better would be to delegate event to document (or BODY) level, something like this:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    console.log('fire -> ' + e.target.id + ' ');
});
```

If clicked element has no ID but still you want to know the closest container clicked (if any and including anyway element itself) with ID, you could use:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    console.log('fire -> ' + ($(e.target).closest('[id]').length ? $(e.target).closest('[id]')[0].id + ' ' : ''));
});
```